# CMake COMPILE_DEFINITIONS triggering incorrect number of arguments

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm having problem understanding how to correctly set the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` target properti in CMake.

my target is `add_library(modelutilities STATIC ${modelutilities_SRCS})`

I if use

```
set(modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE ${modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE} ${Qt5Widgets_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS})
set_target_properties(modelutilities PROPERTIES 
    VERSION "0.0.1"
    SOVERSION 0
    EXPORT_NAME "ModelUtilities"
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${modelutilities_PlatformDir}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${modelutilities_PlatformDir}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${modelutilities_PlatformDir}/bin"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE}
)
```

everything works fine, but if I add another line between them with `set(modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE ${modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE} MODELUTILITIES_LIB)` it stops working complaining that `set_target_properties` was called with the wrong number of arguments.

Anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong?

P.S.

I already tried using doublequotes: `set(modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE ${modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE} "MODELUTILITIES_LIB")`. It did not change anything

P.P.S.

If I `message(STATUS ${modelutilities_COMPILE_DEFINE})` `QT_WIDGETS_LIB;QT_GUI_LIB;QT_CORE_LIB` in the first case and `QT_WIDGETS_LIB;QT_GUI_LIB;QT_CORE_LIB;MODELUTILITIES_LIB` in the second

Comment: May I suggest using target_compile_definitions() instead: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html

Comment: That solved my problem. I know it's a workaround but it does the same thing. If you want to put it in an actual answer I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer version of CMake, what is being preached is the idea of targets. So, for example, instead of `include_directories()` it's now preferred to use `target_include_directories()`.

That being the case I think you'd be better served using the preferred `target_compile_definitions()` to set compile definitions for your utilities library.

One advantage you get is that your can scope your compile definitions using the `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` keywords.